# UIPageViewController removes last page when UITextField is tapped

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller, uitextfielddelegate

I have a UIPageViewController (lets call it `IntroPages`) inside a `UIViewController` (`IntroView`) that takes up about half of the screen. I have four pages that I want to be scrollable inside `IntroPages`, lets call them `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`. All of `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` are implemented as separate `UIViewControllers` with their own nibs. `A`, `B` and `C` are static while `D` has a form on it (imagine three sell pages and then a form to, say, sign up). The user can easily swipe through `A`, `B`, `C` and reach `D` but when the user taps a text field on `D` (lets call it `firstName`), `D` completely disappears from `IntroPages` and `IntroPages` starts to show `C` without any exceptions or anything. At this point the user can swipe from `C` to `D` again and this time around `D` would behave just fine.

Additional Information:

1. The delegate of `firstName` is `D`.
2. If I return NO from `-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` `D` does not disappear even the first time but then the keyboard doesn't come up and I need the keyboard to come up.
3. I also tried to make `IntroView` (the `UIViewController` containing the `UIPageViewController`) to be the delegate of `firstName` but that did not work either i.e. gave the same problem.
4. I am using ARC

My first thought was that `D` is somehow getting released but that is not the case. I created a `-dealloc` function for `D` and put a break point there but D disappears well before the `-dealloc` is called on it. In fact the `-dealloc` is called on it only once the user swipes from `C` to `D` a second time. This tells me that the `UIPageViewController` is deallocating the first instance of D when the second instance of D is supplied to it.